# Access 2016 .accde file crashes on multiple computers

Tags: ms-access

I have a really weird problem with Access 2016 .accde file. This .accde file is a frontend with linked backend tables.

We are a small group of 10 people using the same database.
Here is my problem: if / when we open the front end saved as .accdb file (default Access database format) everything works fine for all 10 people.
When I compile this .accdb file and create an .accde file, I can open it fine on my computer but it will crash if I open it on other user's computer.
If I take the same .acccdb file, compile it and create .acccde file on another computer, then it will open fine on that computer but will crash on mine.
The files (both frontend and backend) are saved on a network share.

What I tried so far:

1. create a blank new database, imported all objects, re-added the references and compiled
2. added "Option Explicit" in all modules and compiled
3. Opened Access in decompile mode and compiled/recompiled again

What else am I missing? How can I make sure that single .accde file can be opened by several users?

Right now my "workaround" is using .accdb file but I don't really like this approach since all users have access to the code in the forms and modules.

This is a relatively new behavior. We have been using this .accde frontend for several years now until it started crashing a couple of months ago.

Comment: Did you check [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fixes-or-workarounds-for-recent-issues-in-access-54962069-14f4-4474-823a-ff7e5974a570)? Also, make sure all installations are updated. Further, always publish a copy of the FE to each user - see my [article](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html?preview=X8LitkMCd/Y%3D).

Comment: My guess: you have a Reference (VBA Editor - References) in your project, that is installed in different versions on the different computers. With an .accdb, Access can silently adapt to the different version, with an .accde it can't.

Comment: Thanks @Andre, you were right. The database used reference for Acrobat library and we had different versions (I have 2022 and my colleague has Acrobat 2017). Once I removed the form with Acrobat code everything went back to normal.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav! I read your article and it was very helpful.